# How do I format text column with year to date format in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

See Attached Image. I imported data with a date column (red area). I realized I needed to change it to date format so I created a new column and entered the formula (blue area) to change the column to a date format, however if you look at the green area, the year is not lining up starting from 2013. How can I fix this? Also my data points are annual so I don't need the "day", "month" format, I just want the year if possible.[image]

Comment: Why do yo uneed to format it as a new column? why do you not just format the Calendar Year column?

Comment: @Aldert I have tried doing that, however all my dates change to 1905 and I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: I believe this is your problem, the data you are working with are not proper dates. Please check if your column is a date If not you can pass us some raw data and we can help you converting it to proper dates

Comment: What data you actually wants in your green part? You have a 4 character data like 2013. So what is your logic for interpreting this value to a real date time formar?

Answer (score 1):

This formula is trying to parse textual representation of a date, while here you have the year part only. Also, parsing is unnecessary complicated for your case. Just use [DATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/date-function-dax) function to construct a date from parts, like this:

```
dateFormatted = DATE([Calendar Year], 1, 1)
```

Which should give you January 1st date in each year (which I guess is the desired result):

[image]